# Content types accessible to a role

Tags: nodes, services, 8

I have a requirement to return a list of content types accessible to a user in JSON format using services module.

I have followed this approach:

1. Used Content Access Control module to set the access permission to a particular role to which the user belongs.
2. Set up a custom resource type for the services module to send the content list in JSON format.
3. Implemented oauth to authorize the request.
4. I could send all the content types present in the drupal setup using my custom resource for services module.

Now I want to check the permissions as declared by the Content access module for a role to access the content types.

I am a beginner with drupal and php programming. I am just trying to ready a module which communicates with my android client. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I followed RajeevK's advice to get the list of permissions from the role_permission table (actually I accessed this using phpmyadmin inerface).

But the permissions declared by the `content_access` module such as `view any <content-type> content` are not listed in the role_access.

Since I have accepted the answer here, I will spawn a new thread and rephrase this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good. I hope you are using D7.

So lets start with the finding the machine name of the permission which get saved with the user_role when you enable the permission for particular user type.

These are them -

administer services,
get any binary files,
get own binary files,
save file information,
get a system variable,
set a system variable,
perform unlimited index queries.

Get you RID from the table ROLE by searching your NAME.ROLE

Get the list of PERMISSION from table ROLE_PERMISSION by RID.ROLE_PERMISSION

List anywhere and do what you want...

Enjoy :)

Comment: Suggestions from @RajeevK helped me to get the list of permissions, I am working on the module will report back asap.